# Evaluating $\sum\frac{\sin(n)}{n^a}$

Tags: summation

I have a function defined as:
$$S(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^a}$$
My question is for what values of $a$ is this convergent, and how can I evaulate this?

For starters, I know that $S(a)$ is definately convergent  for a $a\ge2$ since:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^a}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^a}$$
So we can use $\zeta(a)$ as the upper limit for the series, which makes me think I can extend this convergence to $a>1$. However, I have no idea how I would evaluate this. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly: the series converges absolutely for $\;a>1\;$ (I regard you mean $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$)...at least.

Comment: This comes very close to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3105348.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The series converges for all $a>0$ by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) as $f(N)=\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n)$ is bounded and $g(n)=\frac{1}{n^a}$ is monotonically decreasing to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
for $a>1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^a}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^a}$$
and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^a}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^a}$$